# How to import Model into a custom rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my lib/tasks folder I added a new .rake file.

In the rake task, I am doing this:

```
p = Post.new( ....)
p.save!
```

When I run my task, I get the error:

```
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Post
```

What do I have to do to import my Post model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm thinking you're probably missing the environment declaration. This is necessary in order for Rake to know about your Rails environment. Your rake task call should look something like this:

```
task :my_rake_task => [:environment] do

    # Your code here

end
```

Let me know if that solves the problem!

Answer (score 5):

You want to make the task dependent on the rails environment. You can do so by specifying the => :environment after the task declaration as such:

```
namespace :my_task do 
  desc "an example task"
  task :create_post => :environment do 
    Post.new .... # the rest of the implementation
  end
end
```